# How do I get real time updates for a users wall in the Facebook sdk for iOS?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to implement real-time(auto updating) wall feed in my app and I don't now how and the Facebook website requires you to do GET and POST commands. Is this possible, and if so how??

Thank So Much In Advance :)

Answer (score 3):

To use [Facebook Real-time updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) you required to use publicly accessible URL as `callback`. So this isn't possible just using standalone application on iOS and you'll need to use some sort of web application/service to handle real-time subscriptions and then pass em to your application.